# How to add plenary plugin using lazy.nvim

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

Here I only see instructions to use plug and packer to install this plugin: https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plenary.nvim` plugin can be installed with `lazy.nvim` plugin manager via a simple config:

```lua
require("lazy").setup({
  "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
})
```